# Tool for mirroring PDF-file?

Tags: pdf

There are plenty of tools that can rotate a PDF. Is there a tool that can mirror it, too?

I am not looking for a solution that first converts to a bitmap, then mirrors and then converts the bitmap to PDF, but for a tool that can do the mirroring with no loss of quality. So in PostScript terms I am looking for `1 -1 scale   0 -height transform`.

Comment: In case you can't find a tool: Use `mutool` to decompress streams in pdf file, open in editor, insert `q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm` (push state, modify transformation matrix) before and `Q` (pop state) after what you want to mirror (use anything to automate). Not sure if you'll need a translation, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @meuh's answer I have built:

https://gitlab.com/ole.tange/tangetools/blob/master/mirrorpdf/mirrorpdf

Answer (score 3):

You can try `pstops` from package `psutils`. Convert the pdf to PostScript using GhostScript's `ps2pdf` first, then apply `H` for a horizontal flip.

```
pdf2ps in.pdf in.ps
pstops H in.ps out.ps
```

The PostScript output looks correct in `gv`, but when I converted it back to pdf with `pdf2ps`, it got flipped vertically too.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm getting `pstops: cannot open input file H` in pstops 2.05. Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: It looks like `pstops` has been greatly changed since the version I used. For example, you now need to use `-S 0H` instead of just `H` and you need to specify the input paper size (e.g. `--inpaper=210mmx297mm` for A4 size). I tried using the latest [github](https://github.com/rrthomas/psutils/releases) version, but the output PostScript showed an error when viewed in `ghostscript`. Perhaps see if you can install an older version, before the change to version 2.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use following command line syntax of pstops tool to flip one A4 page:

```
pstops -P A4 -S 0H in.ps out.ps
```